# Problems with Kerberos auth to Active Directory from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, kerberos

I get the error KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN when I try to authenticate to an Active Directory realm from an Ubuntu 22.04 machine joined to the domain, using Kerberos.

I have a Windows machine joined to the same domain and I have no issues with the Windows machine.

I'm also unable to nslookup the Ubuntu machine from the DC but I can ping it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with DNS. There was no A-record in the DNS for the Ubuntu clients. The AD-join process for Ubuntu described [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad) doesn't seem to automatically add the record. Adding the A-record manually to the DNS fixed the issue.